# Differences between printing a pointer with and without & in C99

Tags: c, pointers, c99

Consider the following code:

```
    const char* text = "hi";
    printf("%s\n",text);
    printf("%p\n", &text);
    printf("%p\n", text);
```

From where does every `printf` takes the value it prints?

What are the differences?

Comment: It takes the value from its argument.:)

Comment: `&text` is the _address_ of the pointer, which is also a pointer, `text` is the value of the pointer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So let's remember that a pointer is a memory address. `text` is, as I suspect you know, a pointer to the first (or 0th, depending on how you like to think about it) block of a char array. The `&` is the "address" operator, which returns the memory address (that is, a pointer to...) whatever comes after it. Since the literal pointer value of `text` is itself some kind of data, it has to be stored somewhere in memory. So `&text` returns the address of where the value of `text` is stored. Like this:
[image: POINTERS!!!]

Comment: Thanks I understand better now. Is it true that `text` is stored in the code segement the `&text` in the stack?

Comment: well, sort of.  However, the `&text` is a value that will be stored on the stack as a parameter to the call to the `printf()` function,, just like any other parameter to a function.

Comment: the `text` variable is stored on the stack.  the location of the `&text` could be a value in the .text section of the executable image as part of the instruction or it could be a value in a register, generated by the code.  Which location is true will depend on the underlying CPU and the compiler